# Jquery + click + image swaps + IE6 = I hate that browser

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6

I am having an issue with swapping images in IE6.  Works fine in all browser except that one.

Here is the following code:

```
$(function() {
   $("#image1").click(function() {
       $(this).attr('src', '/v12/images/small/sm-wall-1-on.png');                    
       $('#image2').attr('src', '/v12/images/small/sm-wall-2.png');  
       $('#image3').attr('src', '/v12/images/small/sm-wall-3.png'); 
   });
 });
```

Then here is the HTML

```
<li style="padding:3px;"><img id="image1" src="/v12/images/small/sm-wall-1-off.png" style="border:0px; width:95px; height:75px;" class="pngfix" alt=""  /></li>
<li style="padding:3px;"><img id="image2" src="/v12/images/small/sm-wall-2-selected.png" class="pngfix" style="border:0px; width:95px; height:75px;" class="pngfix" alt="" /></li>
<li style="padding:3px;"><img id="image3" src="/v12/images/small/sm-wall-3.png" class="pngfix" style="border:0px; width:95px; height:75px;" class="pngfix" alt=""  /></li>
```

So basically if I click on one of the images I want to swap out the others along with the one I just clicked.  IE6 hides all images as soon as I perform the click.

Thoughts?

Comment: Could it be related to the "pngfix" class you have on the images, what does this class do and do you have some JS code associated with it ?

Comment: I am sooo lucky that our customer has finally removed the IE6 requirement from new projects :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

google is your friend:

http://wolfram.kriesing.de/blog/index.php/2007/change-img-src-for-ie

it seems to be a problem in IE that is widely known.

my search terms: ie changing img src

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the img tags, you could use a span with a CSS class containing the background-image attribute, then have your click function just change the class.

Basically, the same concept as [CSS Sprites](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites/), but instead of changing the position of the background image, you change the URL. I've used it before in IE6, and it worked fine.